# Service fabric - Updating static configuration files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-on-premises

I am currenlty running an on-premise 3 node cluster with service fabric.

I have a statefull service which has a .csv file containing a complex configuration for my service, and I would like to open a REST endpoint for updating this configuration dynamically.

So, in order to sync the state I could use a reliable dictionary serialize my csv configuration and save it.

What I dont know how to do is to make sure that even after a power-shortage (which is defined as a non-reliable action), the configuration will be saved (since the CSV is saved on the working directory and not in the image store).

I thought about upgrading the service on each update of the CSV, but it seems really exxcessive and will result in multiple application versions provisioned. Is there any standard way to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.csv` file is a requirement, one could treat the `.csv` file that is deployed with the service as default configuration. So, when the service starts, it could perform the following actions to load in configuration:

1. Load the `.csv` default settings into memory.
2. Load any settings stored in Reliable Collections and merge with the default settings previously loaded from the `.csv` file.

In this way, the dynamically updated settings will be replicated reliably due to using the Reliable Collections, and the `.csv` is already replicated due to being a default artifact deployed with all replicas of the service.

Comment: Reliable collections arent persistent through disasters (such as all vm's powering down).

Comment: Reliable collections persist and replicate to disk. If the disaster is a power outage, the data is safe. If the disaster is a flood that destroys the disks, then yes, data will be lost. See [reliable collection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections).